# web page for authorization is too large in mobile

Tags: mobile, authorization, html, onedrive

I'm a developer using REST API in mobile. 
During I test log-in in the phone, I found that 
the web page for authorization is too large in mobile.
Is there webpage for mobile in OneDrive to authorization? 
If somebody know that, please, answer it.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx

I get solution from upper site.

add option "display=touch".